# Subscript operator precedence

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

The subscript operator has the second highest operator precedence (see [the table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)). However, it seems to behave as if it had a low precedence. For example:

```
int arr[] = {10,20,30,40,50};
cout << arr[1+2];
```

This code outputs 40, which suggests that the result of `+` was available before the application of the subscript operator, which in turn suggests that `+` has a higher precedence than the subscript operator. What am I missing and how does the high precedence of the subscript operator express itself?

Comment: The `+` is *inside* the `[]`. How could `arr[1+2]` be anything else than `arr[3]`?

Comment: The purpose of precedence is to resolve ambiguities. What is an ambiguity here?

Comment: I quite like this question - we all get confused from time to time. It's well asked.

Comment: @dyukha Can you come up with a situation, in which the high precedence of `[]` is necessary?

Comment: What other results are you imagining could happen that would suggest that `1+2` was evaluated after subscripting?

Comment: The grouping could have been `(cout << arr)[1 + 2]`. Some folk think the precedence of `<<` is too low anyway. But that would be extreme indeed.

Comment: @molbdnilo Given the precedence table, I would say I'd expect to get a syntax error. It should really have a lower precedence, just above the assignment operator.

Comment: Do you also have a question about `(1+2)*3` by any chance?

Comment: @n.m. No, because parentheses here is not an operator. They define an operand for `*`.

Comment: So you have somehow (how?) decided that `()` make an operand of everything that is inside. You have however decided that `[]` do not make an operand out of everything that is inside, despite of obvious similarities between the two syntaxes. Why is it so? Also what about `sin(a+b)/2`? Parentheses do signify an operator (the function call operator) here.

Comment: @n.m. Correct. I could ask the same question about your second example. But, instead of ridiculing the question, can you come up with a situation, in which the high precedence of `[]` is necessary? It's high up there for a reason, isn't it?

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you mean. How would you define such an operator with low preccedence? Do you want `x+y[0]` to mean `(x+y)[0]? What do you want `y[0]+z` to mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subscript operator `[]` is applying to `arr` and the *argument* is 1 + 2. The argument is not relevant to the precedence of the `[]` operator.

Cf. an expression like `1 + arr[1 + 2]`. That is *grouped* as `1 + (arr[1 + 2])` due to the precedence that you cite, **not** `(1 + arr)[1 + 2]` which would be some curious pointer arithmetic!

Comment: Oh, right! It's a binary operator and in functional notation it would look like `[](arr, 1 + 2)`. So, I would write "and the second operand is 1+2". BTW, there are prefix, infix, postfix operators. Is there a category for operators like subscript?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The postscript operator and the function call operator are classified as postfix in the C++ srandard.

Comment: @n.m. What is the postscript operator?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sorry I meant subscript, not postscript.